# How to destroy an X window?

Tags: 20.04, xorg, window, xkill

JetBrains IDEs sometimes leave tiny residual windows (probably supposed to be popups/tooltips) that it forgets to destroy. Is there an Xorg tool to quickly destroy these windows (I don't want to kill the whole process like `xkill` does)?

I'm guessing destroying those *could* cause issues though (e.g. double-free at the Xorg level when the JVM exits), which could explain why such a tool isn't popular.

Thanks in advance

Comment: xkill will do it.